# Reputation leagues: all-time leaders on overview page not the same as in "all time" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, reputation-leagues, stackexchange.com

I am looking at [stackexchange.com/leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) right now. Here's a snippet of what I see:

[image: Overview]

However, if I click on any of those "all time" links, I get presented with entirely different stats:

- [On Programmers](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/52/alltime/programmers), the all-time leader is Pierre 303, not Developer Art (#10);
- [On Gaming](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/7/alltime/gaming), it's tzenes, not Shaun (#30);
- [On Mathematics](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/alltime/math), it's Qiaochu Yuan, not Arturo Magidin (#2);
- [On WebApps](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/5/alltime/webapps), it's Senseful, not Barry (#3);
- [On OnStartups](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/56/alltime/answers-onstartups), it's Jason, not Pierre 303 (#21);
- and so on.

Ask Ubuntu is actually the odd one out with Oli identified as the all-time leader both on the overview page and in the "all time" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, there was a bug in our query. It's fixed now -- thanks for noticing and reporting it.